# Mongoose calls within async.map hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async.js

Trying to call a Mongoose model within async.map - it times out for a reason I cannot figure out.

```
module.exports = {
  parseProduct: function(m, cb) {
    // This works
    /*     
     var req = require('http').get('http://google.com', function(err, res) {
      cb(err, {});
    });
    */

    // This never returns nor print - times out in my test (with 10s limit)
    Product.findOne({}).exec(function(err, p) {
      console.log(p);
      console.log(err);
      cb(err, {});
    });
  },
  toObject: function(matches, cb) {
    // Loop trough orders
    async.map(matches, this.parseProduct, function(err, items) {
      cb(order);
    });
  }
};
```

It may be that I am just not seeing some glaring error here or is there some Mongoose/async magic I need to be aware of?

Comment: Have you verified that your mongoose connection is open and working? I would also make sure that passing `{}` to `findOne` is actually valid.

Comment: Oh jeezzz....[slap] it was the connection. I was testing it outside my app and evidently forgot to load a connection in Mocha. Thanks for your insight!